# Query for rows that share a set of associations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables: `A`, `B`, `C`.  `B` has a many-to-many relationship with `A` and `C`.

```
A >-< B >-< C
```

Assume every table has a primary key column called id, and the join tables have two columns [a_id, b_id] and [b_id, c_id].

The same row in `B` can be linked to both rows in `A` and `C`. It's fairly straightforward to find rows in `C` that share a specific row in `B` (a series of inner joins).

Given a row id of `A`, I would like to query for all rows in `C` that share ALL rows of `B` associated with that row in `A`:

```
select id,
    (select count(*) from c
        inner join b_c on c.id = b_c.c_id
    ) as c_group,
    (select count(*) from c 
        inner join b_c on c.id = b_c.c_id
        inner join b on b.id = b_c.b_id
        inner join a_b on b.id = a_b.b_id
     where a_id = ?
    ) as a_c_group
from c 
where c_group <= a_c_group;
```

Can this be done via SQL? I'm working in MySQL, so a MySQL-specific solution would be fine.

Comment: Yes, this can be done in SQL.  Please show the format of the tables you are working with and the query(s) you've already created.

Comment: Edited to include all relevant information.

Comment: @Gordon Posted one of my attempts.

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have no duplicates entries?

Comment: Yes.  We have unique constraints on each PK pair in the a_b and b_c tables.

Comment: Do you have any sample data and desired results?

Comment: Share: There exists rows in A_B and B_C such that A_B.b_id = B_C.b_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to compare the count of an inner join of B and C with a inner join of all three tables.

```
SELECT ID
FROM C
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM B_C
  WHERE C_ID = C.ID
) <= (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM B_C INNER JOIN A_B ON B_C.B_ID = A_B.B_ID 
  WHERE C_ID = C.ID AND A_ID = ?
);
```

This covers:

1. If C has no associated B's, it should appear in the result set.
2. If C has associated B's not associated with A, it does not appear in the result set.
3. If A has associated B's not associated with C, but all B's C is associated with, C appears in the result set.

Comment: I would think that a LEFT JOIN would perform better than a correlated subquery here - did you try my updated solution?

Comment: It may be faster, but its incorrect.  You're still trying to find an A and C with at least one B in common.  I need all of them to match (in one direction anyway).

Comment: No, the query I proposed (in the updated solution) will exclude any C that doesn't have all B's in common with A.

Comment: We're going to have to agree to disagree.  I've come up with a solution that fits my needs.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This would yield all the id's for B that are associated with the selected A:

```
SELECT b_id FROM ab WHERE a_id = ?
```

So you need to find any C's that are related to only these B id's and not others.  This can be done by excluding all C's that match other B id's:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM c
LEFT JOIN bc ON c.id = bc.c_id 
  AND bc.b_id NOT IN (SELECT b_id FROM ab WHERE a_id = ?)
WHERE bc.c_id IS NULL
```

Comment: This returns C's where all the associated rows in B are not associated with my A row.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @PeterBratton - you mean that you want C's that match all B's from A, but not other B's?  This can be done as well, but it may be better if you illustrated with sample data what is being returned here that should not be.

Comment: Yes, thats right.  A can have other B's, but C cannot.

Comment: @PeterBratton I see, I gave you the reverse. So you want only the C's where all B's of those C are included in the B's of A - updated for this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want all rows in `C` that have a matching row in `B` that, in turn, match the specified row id in `A`.

This should do it:

```
select
    c.*
from
    c
    join bc on c.id = bc.c_id
where
    exists (select 1
              from ab
             where ab.a_id = 123
                   and ab.b_id = bc.b_id)
```

This assumes that your join (bridge) tables are named `ab` and `bc`, and that you're looking for an a.id of 123

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ced2/2)

Comment: This will return rows in C that share at least one row in B with A.  I'm looking for a query that ensures that all of C's associated B rows are also associated with a specific row in A.